# Google analytics API Classic to Universal

Tags: google-analytics-api

I currently have Google Analytics data extracted through the GA API.

At the moment the analytics account is using Classic GA. Would upgrading GA to Universal Analytics disrupt my current extraction method?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your extraction method and see is it going to be affected by the changes stated below, IMO it most likely will.

> Custom dimensions are the new custom variables in analytics.js or Mobile SDK v2.x or higher.
>   Custom variables have been replaced by custom dimensions in analytics.js, v2.x or higher of the Mobile SDKs, and the Measurement Protocol. If you update your tracking code to use any of these libraries or protocols, you need to replace your custom variables with custom dimensions instead. Learn more about custom dimensions. If you continue to use ga.js or v1.x of the Mobile SDKs, you can continue to use custom variables and these values will continue to be processed. Note, however, that custom variable and custom dimension data can’t be combined in the same report. You must use one report to analyze your custom variable data and another to analyze your custom dimension data. To analyze custom variable and custom dimension data together, export both data sets and combine them outside of Google Analytics. A tool that can help you with this is the Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on.
>   The behavior of setting campaign timeout to 0 in analytics.js differs from that in ga.js.
>
> In classic analytics (ga.js), if you call _setCampaignCookieTimeout() to set campaign timeout to 0, the campaign will persist as long as the current session or for the period the browser is open. Analytics.js does not use campaign cookies, so this feature will not work.

[Source](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hpjNVkIGGYEJ:https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ie)